# How to use overloaded explicit conversion operators?

Tags: f#

I have a type defined in C# like this:

```
struct F {
    public static explicit operator F(long value) {}
    public static explicit operator long(F value) {}
    public static explicit operator F(double value) {}
    public static explicit operator double(F value) {}
    // more conversion operators
}
```

In F# if I want to create it from a long, the only way I found is:

```
let l = F.op_Explicit 3L
```

I tried creating an inline function to make this nicer:

```
let inline f a = F.op_Explicit a
```

But this doesn't compile. I also tried with a member constraint:

```
let inline f (x:^a) = (F: (static member op_Explicit : ^a -> F) x)
```

And that doesn't compile either.

Is it possible to define a function or operator to choose the right overload?

On a side note, it does work nicely in the opposite direction:

```
let f = someF |> int64 // calls the right conversion operator
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not valid to have a member constraint on a single concrete type; however, this might work for you:

```
let inline f (x:^a) : F =
    let inline g x = ((^b or ^c):(static member op_Explicit : ^b -> ^c) x)
    g x
```

This has the more general type `f : ^a -> F when ( ^a or F) : (static member op_Explicit : ^a -> F)`, which is a type that is impossible to manually annotate any value with!

Comment: Great! Only worry I have with this is the warning: "Member constraints with the name 'op_Explicit' are given special status by the F# compiler as certain .NET types are implicitly augmented with this member. This may result in runtime failures if you attempt to invoke the member constraint from your own code." Can I safely ignore it?

Comment: @Asik - In this case you can ignore it.  That limitation applies in certain cases where the compiler acts as though there is an op_Explicit even though there isn't really one there.  For instance, if you extract `g` from my answer into its own definition, calling `(g 1 : int64)` will compile (because the compiler pretends there's an explicit conversion from int to int64), but will fail at runtime (because there's no such member in reality; the conversion is normally handled by the execution environment itself).